# How to add Sphider search to my website? "Cannot connect to database"

Tags: mysql, sphider

I downloaded the [Sphider search engine](http://www.sphider.eu/) and I am currently trying to run it via my localhost. I extracted it in my root folder and made a search bar in HTML:

```
<div id="searchwrapper">
<form action="../sphider-1.3.5/search.php" method="get" title="eurobytes search">
<input type="text" class="searchbox" name="s" value="" action="../sphider-1.3.5/include/js_suggest/suggest.php" columns="2" autocomplete="off" delay="1500" bgcolor="transparent"/>
<input type="hidden" name="search" value="1">
<input type="image" src="../images/search.png" height="15" class="searchbox_submit" value="search" />
</form>
</div>
```

but when I type something in I get this error:

> Cannot connect to database, check if username, password and host are correct.

I am pretty new to MySQL I read the `install.txt`, in the sphider-1.3.5 folder, and did the following:

> mysql -u your username -p Enter your password when prompted. b) in
>   MySQL, type: CREATE DATABASE sphider_db;

But, when I type in `CREATE DATABASE sphider_db` I get this:

[image: create-database]

I don't know what to type now. I tried `sphider_db` `exit` but nothing happens?

Sorry if this problem is common sense to most, but I just started playing with MySQL/Sphider.

Comment: The MySQL client likes you to finish statements with semicolons.

Comment: Thanks that worked. but the error still remains(Cannot connect to database, check if username, password and host are correct.)

Comment: Have you edited database.php? Sounds like configuration issue...Are you certain what your db name, username and pw are? You should include snippets of every piece of code you've edited...

Comment: @RenoDimitrova if was a configuration error, please put it as an answer so i can accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you edited settings/database.php? Sounds like a configuration issue...
Here are 2 steps to start troubleshooting:

1. Check what your database name, username and pw are.
2. Make sure you've edited database.php with that information.

Here is the code snippet from database.php you need to edit with your db settings and user credentials (v1.3.5)

```
/*********************** 
Database 1 settings
***********************/

// Name of database
$database1 = "test";

// MySQL User
$mysql_user1 = "test-user";

// MySQL Password
$mysql_password1 = "test-user-pw";

// MySQL Host
$mysql_host1 = "localhost";

 // Prefix for tables
$mysql_table_prefix1 = "test_";

// Status of database
$db1_set = "1";
```

Comment: Thanks. I eventually found out myself, that i didn't edit my settings, and completely forgot about this question!