# How to add a custom search box to pages in my website after installing Sphider?

Tags: php, sphider

I just installed the search engine Sphider on my website and was wondering how I could implement a search box on my home page (and every other page) so that the search results can appear on my home page.

At the moment, all the searching is done on a seperate page that came with sphider.

Comment: Which spider are u using ? Can u please post the code of that new page created by spider.

Comment: @M.S.P: I think OP is using the software http://www.sphider.eu/

Comment: Related questions: [How to add Sphider search to my website? “Cannot connect to database”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11180289/1591669) ··· [Integrating Sphider search engine in to website](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22290306/1591669)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out how, I had to copy the code from the default folder sphider-1.3.6/template/standard/search-form.php and just simply paste that code anywhere I wanted a search box to appear.